# Music notation via latex / pandoc markdown

Tags: markdown, music

I like how you can embed equations in pandoc-flavored markdown, by putting the equation in between dollar signs, like this:

```
$$ \int^{+\infty}_0 \frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x}} dx$$
```

(see how it renders here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1279592/definite-integral-of-cos-x-sqrtx )

And then it can be converted to pdfs and html like this:

```
pandoc -s inputfile.md -o outputfile.pdf
pandoc -s --mathjax inputfile.md -o outputfile.html
```

Is there a similar thing for music notation, whereby you can enter something into your markdown file to produce musical notation?

The music stack exchange seems to use ABCjs and jTab for scores and chord charts, but I don't know how to incorporate these things into my own markdown: https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2581/jtab-and-abcjs-formatting-sandbox

Comment: Possibly related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/855/can-i-create-music-sheets-with-latex or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136571/musixtex-vs-lilypond